# 'Assertion failed error while im trying to read frame with opencv'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pytorch, transfer-learning

I'm trying to use a .pt model to detect an object via webcam. When I execute this code:

```py
# Importamos librerias
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas

# Leemos el modelo
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom',
                       path = 'C:/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Documentos/jupyterbooks/detector.pt')

# Realizo Videocaptura
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# Empezamos
while True:
    # Realizamos lectura de frames
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Correccion de color
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Realizamos las detecciones
    detect = model(frame)
    
    # Mostramos FPS
    cv2.imshow('Detector de Figuras', np.squeeze(detect.render()))

    # Leemos el teclado
    t = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if t == 27:
        break`

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It's giving me this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I'm new into this so I really don't know why is giving me this type of error.
best regards,
maximiliano

I'm expecting to solve this error so I can test my model in my webcam.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your `frame` is empty. That means the webcam did not load properly. You may check something like `print(frame.shape)` just after `cap.read()` and see what it prints. If it is not empty, it will print the webcam frame size. Make sure your webcam is in location `1` as you specified. If you have only one webcam, it should be `0`.